# npm local webserver serves wrong project

Tags: npm, next.js

I'm new to Javascript development and have a question how to run a next.js project on my local machine. I have a `/projects` folder which contains several projects...

```
/projects/project1 (SvelteKit)   
/projects/project2 (Next.js)
```

When I'm in the `/projects/project2` folder and run "`npm run dev`" and go to `localhost:3000` then the homepage of `project1` gets displayed on my browser.

What do I have to do in order that project2 gets displayed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A hard reload / empty cache did the job